# How to design fully rounded button in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I'm creating an application for iOS 7 and i want a fully rounded button like in calling keypad.
Does anyone know how we can make button to be fully rounded for iOS 7, also is it possible to set an image for rounded button ?

Comment: post some code what u tried ?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, easy.  You need to add the quartzcore framework, and the frame for your button must be square, equal width and height.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.size.height/2.0;
myButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
myButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
myButton.layer.backgroundColor =[UIColor cyanColor].CGColor;
myButton.backgroundColor = nil;
```

Edit addition for ALSO setting image..

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:foobar];
[myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//May as well ditch the colours set to .layer if you do this
```

or you could do something like this:

```
[myButton setImage:[self generateButtonImageOfSize:myButton.frame.size] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


-(UIImage *)generateButtonImageOfSize:(CGSize )buttonSize{
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(buttonSize, NO , 0);

 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

 CGRect br = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

 CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, br);
 CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, br);


//theres a pretty circle, wanna draw other stuff? do it here..




 UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Ha wow there was no answer when I started typing that in

Comment: question says how to set image in button  so please update your answer

Comment: @Rushabh urs also nice answer

Answer (score 2):

// imprort framework in .h file

```
**#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>**

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(135.0, 180.0, 40.0, 40.0);//width and height should be same value
button.clipsToBounds = YES;

button.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the width
button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to use   QuartzCore/QuartzCore  framework . a good tutorial here look at this [round button example](https://github.com/langford/RoundButtonDemo)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways. For example you may use UIImageView for button image and round corners for it

```
UIImageView *avatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 33, 33)];
avatar.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
avatar.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
avatar.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
avatar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
avatar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```